# Why are my application's screens joining together?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am making the login and signup page for an app using kivy, but when I run the program both the screens
are joining together.
Please help me.
This is my python code:-

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_file('design.kv')

LabelBase.register(name= "oswald",
fn_regular= "oswald/Oswald-Regular.ttf")


class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def sign_up(self):
        self.manager.current = "signup_screen"

class SignupScreen(Screen):
    pass

class RootWidget(Screen):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

This is my kivy code:-

```
<LoginScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            Label: 
                text: "User Login"
            TextInput:
                hint_text: "Username"
            TextInput:
                hint_text: "Password"
            Button:
                text: "Login"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Button:
                text: "Forgot Password?"
            Button: 
                text: "Signup here"
                on_press: root.sign_up()


<SignupScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Label:
            text: "Signup for lots of fun!!!"
        TextInput:
            hint_text: "Username"
        TextInput:
            hint_text: "Password"
        Button:
            text: "Signup"

<RootWidget>:
    LoginScreen:
        name: "login_screen"
    SignupScreen:
        name: "signup_screen"
```

This is how it is supposed to look:-

[Login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAMNG.png)

[Signup page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbGq4.png)

But this is the error page:-

[Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndMxc.png)

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
class RootWidget(Screen):
    pass
```

to:

```
class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass
```

You are adding `Screens` to a `Screen`, when I believe you want to add them to a `ScreenManager`.